# Cross-compilation with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, cross-platform

I'm using VS2019 under Windows 10 and I'm trying to figure out how to compile for the non-Windows platforms. I'm aware that only some languages support cross-compilation (C# being one of them). So I decided to start off with one of Microsoft's own examples (the Console App for .NET Core). When asking VS2019 to create the Console project, it shows me various image icons which suggest that it'll be buildable for Windows, Linux and macOS - but no matter what I do, I can only make it build the Windows target.

After a bit of research I realized that I need to add this line to my C# project file:-

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64;ubuntu.16.10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

but even after adding that line (and re-loading / re-building the project) it staunchly refuses to build anything apart from the Windows target. Over on CodeGuru, one of the devs there tried it for me (under VS2017) and managed to make it work - but I've tried it in VS2019 and also VS2015 and I can't make it work in either of them. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong??

[Edit...]
Thanks Magnetron - if I press **Build->Publish** I see a totally different dialog from the one you're seeing (and it's the same in both VS2015 and VS2019):-

[image: My Publish dialog]

Even if I follow the **Next** or **Finish** buttons I never see the Create Profile option :(

Answer (score 2):

Go to Build > Publish, select Folder and click on Create Profile

[image]

Then Click on Edit and change the `Deployment Mode` to `Self-contained`. At last, you can specify the target OS in `Target Runtime`

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can create multiple profiles for each OS, and publish each one individualy as needed.

Edit:

The posted publish dialog is for a .Net Framework Console app, not an .Net Core one. The .Net framework is Windows only, you have to create your project as a .Net Core

[image]

Comment: Thanks Magnetron - a couple of things... firstly, if (in VS2019) I select this project and open its Properties window, the Target Framework property shows as ".NET Core 3.0". Secondly, can I just ask if you're testing in VS2019? (I've been told independently that it works fine in VS2017).

Comment: @johne53 yes, I'm using VS2019 on Windows. Which version are you using (I'm using 16.3.4)?

Comment: Mine's the same (16.3.4). It's getting late here (UK time) so tomorrow I might just uninstall it and re-install. BTW - Stack Overflow isn't notifying me of your replies but I can't find anything in my Settings that'd change that ?!?

Comment: @johne53 Are you talking about the in-site notification or e-mail ones?

Comment: The email ones.

Comment: @johne53 click on your profile>"Edit profile and settings">"Edit e-mail settings" and set the "Inbox" to the desired frequency of notification. The minimum is 3h, so you can't get real time notifications. You can also install the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo!! I just ran the VS2019 installer to remind myself how to uninstall (in preparation for tomorrow) and it told me there's already a 16.3.5 available. 16.3.4 only got installed a few hours ago but for the hell of it, I figured I might as well try the newer version - and it's now working !!!